# BoxSizer in Frame and Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, boxsizer

When i create a BoxSizer like this:

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                      "App",size=(800,600),style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,size=(800,600))
        # create BoxSizer and fill it with elements
```

it works.
But when I do this:

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                      "App",size=(800,600),style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        panelThree(self)

class panelThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,size=(800,600))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,size=(800,600))
        # create BoxSizer and fill it with elements
```

then something goes wrong: all elements are located in the top left corner and they overlap each other. How do I have to use BoxSizer when I want to use it in my class *panelThree* ?
I just took the example from here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/BoxSizerTutorial

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are not adding the following widget to the sizer: self.panel. If you do not add it to the sizer, then it's going to mess up your layout. Personally, I don't think you even need a panel inside a panel. Removing that line will fix the issue:

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                      "App",size=(800,600),style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
        panelThree(self)

class panelThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,size=(800,600))
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self,size=(800,600))
        # create BoxSizer and fill it with elements
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        for item in range(10):
            btn = wx.Button(self, label="Button %s" % item)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```